# Facebook login button gives error all the time

Tags: java, android, android-facebook

I added facebook login to my application but wheneven i click facebook button it gives ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error before asking me any info.

Here are my codes:

My java:

```
package com.bogroup.ucuncuprogram;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;



public class Fireapp extends FragmentActivity {
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    TextView txtstatus;
    LoginButton loginButton;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fireapp);
        txtstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gir();
            }
        });

    }

    private void gir() {

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        txtstatus.setText("basarili "+loginResult.getAccessToken());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        txtstatus.setText("iptal");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        txtstatus.setText("hata "+error.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

My build.grade file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bogroup.ucuncuprogram"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
        // as noted by @Vishnuvathsan you may also need to include
        // variations on the file name. It depends on your dependencies.
        // Some other common variations on notice and license file names
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
ext {
    googlePlayVer = "10.2.0"
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${googlePlayVer}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${googlePlayVer}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:${googlePlayVer}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:${googlePlayVer}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:${googlePlayVer}"
    compile "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.bogroup.ucuncuprogram">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

        >
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            tools:replace="android:value"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ikinciekren">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.IKINCIEKREN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Fireapp">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

Btw my class name is set in facebook developers setting added app id my strings.xml file

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe you have provided the code for pressing the login button.

Comment: can you post your _activity_main.xml_ code for login button.

Comment: Why u extends Fragment Activity

Comment: Just arranged the code but still same result.

Answer (score -1):

i give a full code of facebook integration with app and first u try as a demo and after implement in your app

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CallbackManager callbackManager;
Button share, details;
ShareDialog shareDialog;
LoginButton login;
ProfilePictureView profile;
Dialog details_dialog;
TextView details_txt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    login = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    profile = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
    details = (Button) findViewById(R.id.details);
    login.setReadPermissions("public_profile email");
    share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    details.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    details_dialog = new Dialog(this);
    details_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_details);
    details_dialog.setTitle("Details");
    details_txt = (TextView) details_dialog.findViewById(R.id.details);
    details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            details_dialog.show();
        }
    });

    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
        RequestData();
        share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                details.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                profile.setProfileId(null);
            }
        }
    });
    share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().build();
            shareDialog.show(content);

        }
    });
    login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                RequestData();
                share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        }
    });

}

public void RequestData() {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

            JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
            try {
                if (json != null) {
                    String text = "<b>Name :</b> " + json.getString("name") + "<br><br><b>Email :</b> " + json.getString("email") + "<br><br><b>Profile link :</b> " + json.getString("link");
                    details_txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
                    profile.setProfileId(json.getString("id"));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
    request.setParameters(parameters);
    request.executeAsync();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

put facebook sdk .jar file in your libs folder and add as a library in project
here is link to download facebook sdk
[facebook sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads)

**manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">

</uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />-->
            <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />-->

            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**mainactivity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.facebook.login.widget.ProfilePictureView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="200sp"/>

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:text="Show details"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:text="Share"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```